# Server chose unsupported or disabled protocol: SSLv3

Tags: exception, ssl, jakarta-mail

Trying to connect to an imap server from an app that uses javamail to connect. I can't modify the code, but it's throwing the 'Server chose unsupported or disabled protocol: SSLv3' error, and I can't find a property that I can override to enable that protocol. The server I'm connecting to does not support TLSv1 (yes, it's old).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a specific socket factory using SSLv3 instead of TLSv1 via the `mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory` property of JavaMail (see the [Socket Factories](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javamail-1.4.2/SSLNOTES142.txt) section in the JavaMail release notes and [MailSSLSocketFactory](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory.html)).

Before returning the `SSLSocket` in your `SSLSocketFactory` implementation (`createSocket`), use `setEnabledProtocols` to allow `SSLv3`.